# dev_alert not always printed

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a simple misc device driver for the linux kernel. I have some print messages to aid in debugging. I have tried both `dev_alert` and `dev_crit`

The issue is that some of those are printed, and some are not. and I wonder why?

Below is a sample from my write function:

```
ssize_t misc_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buff,
                size_t count, loff_t *offp)
{
        ssize_t retval;
        dev_crit(my_dev.this_device, "LOG_ENTER: misc_wrrite\n");
        if (count != strlen(MY_UNIQUE_ID)+1) {
                dev_alert(my_dev.this_device, "misc_write: strlen not equal\n");
                retval = -EINVAL;
                goto out;
        }
        if (copy_from_user(my_buff, buff, count)) {
                dev_crit(my_dev.this_device, "misc_write: couldn't copy from userspace\n");
                retval = -EINVAL;
                goto out;
        }
        if (strncmp(MY_UNIQUE_ID, my_buff, count)) {
                dev_crit(my_dev.this_device, "misc_write: string not equal to my unique ID\n");
                retval = -EINVAL;
        } else {
                dev_crit(my_dev.this_device, "The passed value is equal to my unique ID\n");
                retval = count;
        }
out:   
        dev_crit(my_dev.this_device, "LOG_EXIT: misc_wrrite\n");
        return retval;
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this has something to do with Eudyptula challenge (http://eudyptula-challenge.org/). If that indeed is the case, I think you should just submit your code to Little and see what the reply is (rest assured, it's going to be helpful).

Comment: It's related... but It's not the issue... Still want to understand why my debugging messages doesn't make it to the system log. :)

Comment: Which ones do you get to the kernel message buffer? Is there a pattern like messages produced with `dev_crit()` does not end into the kernel message buffer whereas messages produced with `dev_alert` do or vice versa? By "the system log" do you mean the kernel message buffer (ie. stuff produced with `dmesg`) or some log file in (probably) `/var/log`?

Comment: Actually it's random.. for example I have a client application that I test my drive with, so I do it in this steps:  
- `Read from the device.`  
- `Write correct value to the device.`  
- `Write wrong value to the device.`  

With the above scenario it only print the debug messages for the first read throw `dmesg` 
If I commented the reading, it prints the 1st write debug messages and so on.

All this info is printed using `dmesg`

Comment: When I change the dev_crit to pr_crit the messages are printed. !